# Getting most two recent date

Tags: date

if I have a list of date.
eg. Jan 01,2017, Mar 02, 2017, Feb 09,2017, Jun 02,2017

How can I get the most two recent date? Mar 02, 2017 and Jun 02,2017

Comment: It would be good to tag the RDBMS you are using. Also have you tried SELECT TOP 2 and ORDER BY date DESC?

Comment: in addition to @tpet's questions ... are the list of dates in a single row, or spread across multiple rows? instead of going down a list of more questions I'd recommend you take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then come back and update your question with the details we'll need to provide a useful answer

Answer (score 0):

Using PostgreSQL this is pretty easy. The input formats support this form, and you can sort easily and limit to the two most recent dates.

```
SELECT mydate
FROM ( VALUES
  ('Jan 01,2017'::date),
  ('Mar 02, 2017'),
  ('Feb 09,2017'),
  ('Jun 02,2017')
) AS t(mydate)
ORDER BY mydate DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

If some of those dates are ahead of the current date, you may want to add some selectivity,

```
SELECT mydate
FROM ( VALUES
  ('Jan 01,2027'::date),
  ('Jan 01,2029'),
  ('Jan 01,2017'),
  ('Mar 02, 2017'),
  ('Feb 09,2017'),
  ('Jun 02,2017')
) AS t(mydate)
WHERE mydate <= CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY mydate DESC
LIMIT 2;
```